# What linear programming problem do I have?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming, python

I have a number $W\in\mathbb{R}$ and a vector $w=\left[w_1,\dots,w_n\right]^T\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that each $w_i=i\cdot g$ where $g=const$. Usually $n\leq4$. The goal is to find a vector $c=\left[c_1,\dots,c_n\right]^T\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that

1. $\sum_1^nc_iw_i$ is *as close as possible* to $W$ but *doesn't exceed* it
2. $\sum_1^nc_i$ is $\min$
3. smaller $w_i$ are *avoided as much as possible*

Example:

$$W=100$$ $$g=10, n=3\Rightarrow$$
$$w=\left[1\cdot 10, 2\cdot 10, 3\cdot 10\right]^T=\left[10,20,30\right]^T$$
For this setup the best solution would be ***NOT***
$$c=\left[1,0,3\right]^T$$
$$\left(1\cdot10+0\cdot20+3\cdot30=100\right)$$
but rather 
$$c=\left[0,2,2\right]^T$$
$$\left(0\cdot10+2\cdot20+3\cdot30=100\right)$$

Once again, $W,w_i,g$ are **real** numbers, $c_i$ must be **integers**.

After some time of mental work, I'm stuck (I'm not a mathematician) in

- what type of problem it is? integer linear programming?
- point 1 in the list above: is the condition $\sum_1^nc_iw_i\leq W$ is enough to cover the *as close as possible* condition?
- point 3 in the list above: how to formulate this constraint? should I introduce *value* for each $w_i$ (like in the knapsack problem)?
- which programming package in python or R should I use

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your first constraint equivalent to $g\sum i\cdot c_i\le W$ ?

Comment: You want to optimize three criteria at the same time. This is in general not possible. You have to compose a single criterion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want to minimize $\sum c_i$ subject to two constraints: 1. $\sum w_i c_i\leq W$ and 2. smaller $w_i$ should be avoided if possible. I thought the number of constraints is allowed to be more than one...

Comment: I didn't say constraints, I said criteria. You are trying to minimize three things at a time. You can't.

Comment: I don't get your point. If we keep only the first constraint, we end up with the canonical linear program: minimize $\sum c_i$ (i.e. just one "thing") subject to $\sum w_i c_i \leq W$ which obviously has a solution.

Comment: Hem, didn't you say 1. as close as possible, 2. min, 3. as much as possible ? Who is the tallest and largest man on Earth ?

Comment: Yeah, but these words are used for different mathematical objects: 1. $\sum w_i c_i$, 2. $\sum c_i$, and 3. vector $w$. As the example shows: the number 100 can (1.) be split into a (2.) minimal number of summands and this splitting (3.) has no small $w_i$.

Comment: You are free not to believe me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is integer linear programming, with multiple objectives.  One way to handle multiple objectives is to blend them into a single objective, but it sounds like you have a ranking of importance.  In that case, you would optimize the most important (*primary*) objective first: maximize $\sum_i c_i w_i$ subject to $\sum_i c_i w_i \le W$.  Suppose this maximum is $z_1^*$.  Then include an additional (*objective cut*) constraint $\sum_i c_i w_i \ge z_1^*$, and optimize the next (*secondary*) objective: minimize $\sum_i c_i$.  Suppose this minimum is $z_2^*$. Then include a second (*objective cut*) constraint $\sum_i c_i \le z_2^*$, and optimize the third (*tertiary*) objective, which might be to minimize $\sum_i 2^{-i} c_i$.